# bash: compound expression in test command

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

What is the right way in `bash` to do the following:

```
[ -x /path/to/file ] || multiple_actions
```

where `multiple_actions` include e.g. printing some message and `exit 1`

I tried to do it as:

```
[ -x /path/to/file ] || echo Can't execute file; exit 1
```

It works, however I'm not sure if this the right way to do so? May be there are some potential hidden errors?

Comment: `{ echo Can't execute file; exit 1; }`

Comment: Avoid contractions because quote characters are shell syntax.  So:
`{ echo Cannot execute file; exit 1; }`

Comment: Your attempt doesn't work. It exits all the time, not just when the test condition is true.

Comment: I recommend using a normal `if` statement. There's no prize for one-liners (except in Code Golf).

Comment: What you tried does not do what you want. It always exits with status 1. Either use an `if` command (`if ! [ -x ... ]; then this; that; fi` or a `{}` compound command (`[ -x ... ] || { this; that; }`.

Comment: @EricBolinger Or just quote the argument: `echo "Can't execute file"`. Syntax should accommodate data, not the other way around.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet, that comment should be the accepted answer. Care to post it?

Comment: @glennjackman Done (I initially didn't because I was convinced that this was a duplicate but I couldn't find a similar enough question; still I would not be surprised...)

Comment: Make sure you write your error messages to stderr: `echo "Can't execute /path/to/file" >&2`.  But what you probably want to do here is just delete this check entirely.  Rather than: `if ! test -x /path/to/file; echo ... >&2; exit 1; fi; /path/to/file ...`, just do `/path/to/file ... || exit 1`.  You will get a perfectly good error message from the shell telling you that the file is not executable.  (This will also terminate the script if it executes and fails, but you probably want that anyway.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you tried does not do what you want. It always exits with status 1. Either use an `if` command:

```
if ! [ -x ... ]; then this; that; fi
```

or a `{}` compound command:

```
[ -x ... ] || { this; that; }
```